# CSS editor indentation in IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: css, intellij-idea

I am trying to set up 4 default spaces in the CSS editor in IntelliJ 12, so that when I press Enter to create a new line, I get 4 spaces instead of 2 (the current behavior). I already followed the instructions from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/general.html, but for some reason they do not work for me.

This is what it does right now:

```
#wrap1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This is what I need to do:

```
#wrap1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

These are the settings that I have right now, which are not putting 4 spaces on new lines (I know that the sample on the screen-cap is fine, but it does not work that way in the editor):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug. Here are some general-purpose troubleshooting tactics that might fix the issue.

**Invalidate caches:** Go to `File` --> `Invalidate Caches/ Restart` --> `Invalidate Caches and Restart`. *Warning: this will clear your local history.*

**Test with a fresh project:** Create a *new* project in a test directory and check your tab settings. If they work properly in a new project but not in an existing project, there might be something wrong in the project-specific configuration. Backup and delete the `.idea` project configuration directory and re-create the project from scratch.

**Backup and reset your entire configuration:**

1. (Optional but recommended) Backup your configuration with `File` --> `Export Settings`.
2. (Optional but recommended) Invalidate caches as described above before proceeding.
3. Close IntelliJ
4. Find the IntelliJ configuration directory per [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)
5. Rename the directory (such as from `.IntelliJIdea12` to `.IntelliJIdea12.bak`) so that it no longer exists under its original name.

   - You can rename it back to restore original configuration (but try using import settings first).
6. Open IntelliJ with a *new* project and check to make sure the tab settings work now. If they don't, import/ restore your old settings and test with existing project. If they do, reconfigure everything else from scratch, testing your tab settings periodically.

**Upgrade to 13.0 and/or contact support:**

I assume you decided not to upgrade to IntelliJ 13 and/or that your free support period has run out, but I figure I'd mention it just in case.

- Note: Whenever I have delayed upgrading in the past, mysterious bugs would surface with every "patch" upgrade to the old version after a new version was available. I suspect JetBrains does not pay much attention to patch quality for old versions. This may be the case here.

Comment: I tried that already and it does not work. I updated the post with a screen cap of what I have set up.

Comment: @Saymon I added some more troubleshooting tips in my answer.